# AWS Chainlink Quickstart Error - S3 Error Access Denied

Tags: chainlink

I am getting the following error when executing the Quickstart for Chainlink during the AuroraStack execution.

S3 Error: Access Denied

Not very friendly error so I went over to the yaml file.

https://aws-quickstart.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/quickstart-chainlinklabs-chainlink-node/submodules/quickstart-amazon-aurora-postgresql/templates/aurora_postgres.template.yaml

And gave it a read but I really don't see anything that even has it hitting an S3 storage resource.

The error would lead me to believe that the previous YAML file that calls the above is being called and can't even reach the S3 file for Aurora.

Anyone else seen / resolved this issue?

Any ideas are appreciated?

Thanks!

Chris

Ultimately, it was an S3 access issue to the Aurora file inside the chainlink quickstart.  I setup an S3 bucket, redid the files and gave myself permission and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it was an S3 access issue to the Aurora file inside the chainlink quickstart. I setup an S3 bucket, redid the files and gave myself permission and it worked fine.